# How to introduce myself briefly in a get together for new faculty members?

Tags: professorship, career-path, university, tenure-track, social-skills

For the new faculty orientation, there is a get together where they will ask every new faculty member of all departments to say a few words about him/her self.

What are the best practices regarding that? any advice/examples/templates of how to do that briefly, eloquently and professionally?

Comment: Relax.  They don't bite.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Partly, you'll want to **copy what others are doing**.  If everyone else only talks for 15 or 20 seconds, then almost anything that you say in a 3-minute monologue will be poorly received.  Information that you'll likely want to mention includes: **name**, **department**, **research interests**, possibly **where you've just moved from**, and maybe **a bit about you personally** (I enjoy triathlons; married with two kids; active in a barbershop quartet; etc.)  One point about your research interests: keep it **very nontechnical**.  Rather than give many details, say something like *I write computer programs to help blind people use computers*, or *I study 18th century literature, particularly the works of SoandSo*.  Most likely, this activity will be pretty informal.  If you're still a little nervous about it, you might ask another junior faculty member in your department.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have many departments, mostly your speech shouldn't cross 1 minute max. You should include below details.
Full Name and Native Place
Department, 
Job post ( Jr / Sr / Head etc )
Year of experience, Previous work place if any
Specialization/ Research subject, Anything additional course you are taking for future, future prospects.
if time permits abt family. Welcome others and happy to join the team to move further.